# android - drawable in TextView has different size when setting it as resource id than when setting it as Drawable

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

The drawable I set to a TextView has different size in the following two ways of assigning a drawable to a TextView. Can anyone explain why?

1st way - shows smaller and has correct relative size in smaller screens

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawable)
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);
```

2nd way - shows bigger and  in smaller screens it shows really big

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mydrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: `textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.mydrawable, null, null, null);` won't compile - you can't pass nulls for int parameters.

Comment: good point but that was just a mistake writing the question. I edited it

Comment: Use fix height textview.use drawbles mutate method.